# How to get SPFieldChoice values using rest api SharePoint 2013?

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013

I have a choice field in my list. I can get it values using server object model by following way

```
List<string> fieldList;

SPList spList = spWeb.Lists[listName];

SPFieldChoice field = (SPFieldChoice)spList.Fields[fieldName];

fieldList = new List<string>();

foreach (string str in field.Choices){

             fieldList.Add(str);
         }
```

Now I need it badly using rest api. Is it possible using rest api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem.

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "host url"+"_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/fields?$filter=EntityPropertyName eq 'Choice Field Name'",
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.d.results[0].Choices.results);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }

        });
```